# Write trigs in terms of Cosine only

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, term-rewriting

I have a long expression having terms that go in squares like `Sin[x]^2` and `Sin[x/2]^2` and so on... I would like to rewrite my expression such that only Cosines occur (naturally Cos[x]^2 since all the trigs come in squares in my expression). How can I do that?

Comment: I doubt there's a way to do this simply. You'd essentially have to go through all possible ways to represent `Sin[x]^2` and choose the ones specifically which only have Cosine terms, which is a problem in itself cause you'd have to tell Mathematica to "ignore" constant terms like 1 in `1-Cos[x]^2`. That expression has full form `Plus[1,Times[-1,Power[Cos[x],2]]]`, so I really doubt you can have Mathematica choose out the things you want.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question what the best approach might be, since we don't have a good example expression, but perhaps a simple approach might actually work, something like `Expand@expr /. Sin[x_]^2 :> 1 - Cos[x]^2 // Expand`. Again, it depends on the complexity of your expression, but perhaps it's a start.

Comment: OK @march I'll give that a try